How do you define the composition of two $\mathbb{S}$-modules?
I am reading the book "Algebraic Operads" by J. L. Loday and B. Vallete. I am stuck with the definition of composition of $\mathbb{S}$-modules in Sec-5.1.6, pg. 99. Below I have written down all the required definitions and have posted my question at the end.
An $\mathbb{S}$-module over $\mathbb{K}$ is a family $M = (M(0), M(1), M(2), \ldots, M(N), \ldots)$ of right $\mathbb{K}[\mathbb{S}_n]$-modules $M(n)$.
Tensor product of two $\mathbb{S}$-module:
The tensor product of two $\mathbb{S}$-module is defined as follows (cf. Section 5.1.4): Let $M$ and $N$ be two $\mathbb{S}$-modules. Then their tensor product is the $\mathbb{S}$-module $M \otimes N$ defined by
$$M \otimes N (n) := \bigoplus_{i+j=n} \mathrm{Ind}^{\mathbb{S}_n}_{\mathbb{S}_i \times \mathbb{S}_j} M(i) \otimes M(j) \cong \bigoplus_{i+j=n} M(i) \otimes M(j) \otimes \mathbb{K}[Sh(i,j)]$$
where $\mathrm{Ind}^{\mathbb{S}_n}_{\mathbb{S}_i \times \mathbb{S}_j} M(i) \otimes M(j)$ is the induced representation of $\mathbb{S}_n$ defined in Appendix A.1.3, pg 458. It says the following: Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. If $M$ is a right $H$-module, then the induced representation is the following representation of $G$ (i.e., a left $K[G]$-module) $$\mathrm{Ind}^G_H M := M \otimes_H \mathbb{K}[G].$$
Question 1:
I am a bit confused with the definition of the tensor product of two $\mathbb{S}$-module $M$ and $N$. The definition of $\mathbb{S}$-module says it is a family of right $\mathbb{K}[\mathbb{S}_n]$-modules. Then by definition $M \otimes N (n)$ should be a right $\mathbb{K}[\mathbb{S}_n]$-module. But the induced representation $\mathrm{Ind}^{\mathbb{S}_n}_{\mathbb{S}_i \times \mathbb{S}_j} M(i) \otimes M(j)$ is a representation of $\mathbb{S}_n$, hence is a left $\mathbb{K}[\mathbb{S}_n]$-module and not a right $\mathbb{K}[\mathbb{S}_n]$-module. This has confused me, as I am unable to understand how to make $\mathrm{Ind}^{\mathbb{S}_n}_{\mathbb{S}_i \times \mathbb{S}_j} M(i) \otimes M(j)$ a right $\mathbb{K}[\mathbb{S}_n]$-module? Therefore, assuming the definition of tensor product to be
$$M \otimes N(n) = \bigoplus_{i+j=n} M(i) \otimes M(j) \otimes \mathbb{K}[Sh(i,j)]$$
I have proceeded further.
Question 2:
Let $N$ be an $\mathbb{S}$-module. Then can we tell that the following equality holds? If yes, how should I proceed to prove it? I also could not prove it for the case $k=2$.
$$N^{\otimes k} (n) = \bigoplus_{i_1 + \cdots + i_k =n} \mathrm{Ind}^{\mathbb{S}_n}_{\mathbb{S}_{i_1} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{S}_{i_k}} \big(N(i_1) \otimes \cdots \otimes N(i_k)\big)
\cong \bigoplus_{i_1 + \cdots + i_k=n} N(i_1) \otimes \cdots \otimes N(i_k) \otimes \mathbb{K}[Sh(i_1,\ldots,i_k)]$$
Composition of two $\mathbb{S}$-module:
Given two $\mathbb{S}$-module $M$ and $N$ their composite is the $\mathbb{S}$-module $$M \circ N(n) := \bigoplus_{k \ge 0} M(k) \otimes_{\mathbb{S}_k} N^{\otimes k}(n) 
\cong \bigoplus_{k \ge 0} \Big(M(k) ~~\otimes_{\mathbb{S}_k} \bigoplus_{i_1 + \cdots + i_k =n} \mathrm{Ind}^{\mathbb{S}_n}_{\mathbb{S}_{i_1} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{S}_{i_k}} \big(N(i_1) \otimes \cdots \otimes N(i_k)\big)\Big)$$
Assuming the equality mentioned in "Question 2" holds, we get
$$M \circ N(n) = \bigoplus_{k \ge 0} P(k) = \bigoplus_{k \ge 0} \Big(M(k) ~~\otimes_{\mathbb{S}_k} \bigoplus_{i_1 + \cdots + i_k =n} N(i_1) \otimes \cdots \otimes N(i_k) \otimes \mathbb{K}[Sh(i_1,\ldots,i_k)]\Big)$$
Example:
The authors have provided an example of the composition of two $\mathbb{S}$-modules in 5.1.9, pg 100: Let $M$ and $N$ be two $\mathbb{S}$-modules with $M(0)=0=N(0)$ and $M(1) = \mathbb{K} = N(1)$ then
$$M \circ N (2) = M(2) \oplus N(2)$$
$$M \circ N(3) = M(3) \oplus \big(M(2) \otimes \mathrm{Ind}^{\mathbb{S}^3}_{\mathbb{S}_2} N(2)\big) \oplus N(3)$$
Question 3:
Assuming the equality in "Question 2" I did the computation for $M \circ N(3) = \bigoplus_{k \ge 0} P(k) = P(1) \oplus P(2) \oplus P(3)$ (note that since $M(0)=0 \implies P(0)=0$ and for $k > 3$ we have $P(k) = 0$ since $i_1 + \cdots + i_k = 3$ implies one of $i_1,\ldots,i_k$ say $i_j$ is $0$, which implies $N(i_j)=0$). Now computing $P(1)$, $P(2)$, and $P(3)$ we get:
$$P(1) = M(1) \otimes_{\mathbb{S}_1} \big(N(3) \otimes \mathbb{K}[Sh(3)]\big) \cong M(1)~ \otimes_{\mathbb{S}_1} N(3) \cong N(3)$$
$$P(2) = M(2) \otimes_{\mathbb{S}_2} \Big( \big(N(1) \otimes N(2) \otimes \mathbb{K}[Sh(1,2)]\big) \oplus \big(N(2) \otimes N(1) \otimes \mathbb{K}[Sh(2,1)]\big)\Big)$$
$$P(3) = M(3) \otimes_{\mathbb{S}_3} \big(N(1) \otimes N(1) \otimes N(1) \otimes \mathbb{K}[Sh(1,1,1)]\big) \cong M(3) \otimes_{\mathbb{S}_3} \mathbb{K}[\mathbb{S}_3] \cong M(3)$$
My question is how to show $P(2) \cong M(2) \otimes\mathrm{Ind}^{\mathbb{S}_3}_{\mathbb{S}_2}N(2)$? The authors have mentioned, "Since $\mathbb{S}_2$ is exchanging the two summands we get the expected result". I could not decipher the meaning of this.

Is $\mathbb{K}$ a field? What is $\mathbb{S}$, a ring?

This is not research level.

@VladimirDotsenko: At the beginning of this post I mentioned "This should be a math.stack question, but I am posting it on math.overflow so that someone who knows the theory of operads might provide some helpful comments and answers." But someone edited the post and removed it.

Well, if you realize this should be an MSE question, it is especially inappropriate to post it on MO.

(These multi-part questions are always awkward to handle, because different people may answer different parts, and then how to award credit?)
For question 1, I find that the shuffle notation doesn't make it easier to keep track of what's going on, which is that the tensor product is defined by
$$(M \otimes N)(n) = \bigoplus_{i+j=n} (M(i) \otimes N(j)) \otimes_{S_i \times S_j} \mathbb{K}S_n.$$
Here $S_i \times S_j$ acts on the right on $M(i) \otimes N(j)$ and on the left on $\mathbb{K}S_n$ (because any subgroup inclusion $G \hookrightarrow H$ or for that matter any homomorphism $\phi: G \to H$ gives a left action of $G$ on $\mathbb{K}H$, via $g \cdot h = \phi(g)h$). So you take the tensor product of a right $(S_i \times S_j)$-module with a left $(S_i \times S_j)$-module. But at the same time, $\mathbb{K}S_n$ is not merely a left $(S_i \times S_j)$-module; it's a left $(S_i \times S_j)$- right $S_n$-module, in other words a bimodule, and the right $S_n$-module structure on $\mathbb{K}S_n$ induces a right $S_n$-module structure on
$$\bigoplus_{i+j=n} (M(i) \otimes N(j)) \otimes_{S_i \times S_j} \mathbb{K}S_n$$
which answers the first question. (Where you say $M \otimes_H \mathbb{K}[G]$ is a left $G$-module, I say it's a right $G$-module.)
I'll come back to the other questions later when I have more time, unless someone else gets there first.

For question 2: first of all, the shuffle description doesn't seem right to me. I'll come back to this in a moment. (It seems Bruno Vallete is not a member of the MO community; I wonder how he would respond.) Anyway, it would be better to describe $N^{\otimes k}$ in terms of induced representations:
$$N^{\otimes k} (n) = \bigoplus_{i_1 + \cdots + i_k =n} \mathrm{Ind}^{\mathbb{S}_n}_{\mathbb{S}_{i_1} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{S}_{i_k}} \big(N(i_1) \otimes \cdots \otimes N(i_k)\big)$$
or in other words
$$N^{\otimes k} (n) = \bigoplus_{i_1 + \cdots + i_k =n} \big(N(i_1) \otimes \cdots \otimes N(i_k)\big) \otimes_{S_{i_1} \times \ldots \times S_{i_k}} \mathbb{K}S_n.$$
To see this is correct, it is clarifying to understand the tensor product of $\mathbb{S}$-modules in terms of universal properties (a useful catchphrase here is "Day convolution"). Consider $\mathbb{S}$ as equivalent to the symmetric monoidal groupoid of finite sets and bijections, with tensor product obtained by restricting the coproduct = cocartesian monoidal product $+$ on finite sets and all functions between them, to finite sets and bijections between them. Let
$$y: \mathbb{S} \to \mathrm{Mod}_K(\mathbb{S})$$
be the functor that sends the $n$-element set $[n]$ to $\mathbb{K}[S_n]$. Then the assignment $(M, N) \mapsto M \otimes N$, called variously the Cauchy product or the Day convolution, is up to unique isomorphism the unique functor that extends the functor
$$\mathbb{S} \times \mathbb{S} \overset{+}{\to} \mathbb{S} \overset{y}{\to} \mathrm{Mod}_K(\mathbb{S})$$
along $y \times y$ to a functor
$$\mathrm{Mod}_K(\mathbb{S}) \times \mathrm{Mod}_K(\mathbb{S}) \to \mathrm{Mod}_K(\mathbb{S})$$
that is $\mathbb{K}$-linear and cocontinuous (colimit-preserving) separately in the first and second arguments $M, N$. Once this universal property is understood as the main point of the construction, then it is relatively straightforward to see that symmetric monoidal product $+$ induces a symmetric monoidal structure for the Cauchy product $\otimes$. This implies that iterated tensor products $M_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes M_k$ are given by the formula
$$\bigoplus_{i_1 + \cdots + i_k =n} \big(M_1(i_1) \otimes \cdots \otimes M_k(i_k)\big) \otimes_{S_{i_1} \times \ldots \times S_{i_k}} \mathbb{K}S_n$$
precisely because this construction is also $\mathbb{K}$-linear and cocontinuous in each of its separate arguments $M_1, \ldots, M_k$. This answers question 2.
The reason the shuffle formula looks wrong to me can be illustrated very simply. Take $M$ so that $M(i) = 0$ for $i \neq 1$ and $M(1) = \mathbb{K}[S_1]$; take $N$ so that $N(i) = 0$ for $i \neq 1$ and $N(2) = \mathbb{K}[S_2]$. As a module over $S_1 \times S_2 \cong S_2$, the only nontrivial $M(i) \otimes N(j)$ is isomorphic to the right $S_2$-module $\mathbb{K}[S_2]$. The induced representation formula gives
$$(M(1) \otimes N(2)) \otimes_{S_1 \times S_2} \mathbb{K}[S_3] \cong \mathbb{K}[S_2] \otimes_{S_2} \mathbb{K}[S_3] \cong \mathbb{K}[S_3]$$
as the only nontrivial $(M \otimes N)(n)$; here $n = 3$. But if we try the shuffle formula, we get
$$\mathbb{K}[S_2] \otimes \mathbb{K}[S_2\backslash S_3]$$
which is a very different right $S_3$-module. Indeed, if we identify $S_2$ with the subgroup of $S_3$ generated by the transposition $(1\; 2)$, then $(1\; 2)$ acts trivially on the construction that uses the shuffle product (because it acts trivially on the right on $\mathbb{K}[S_2\backslash S_3]$), but it acts nontrivially on $\mathbb{K}[S_3]$.
(Will get back to question 3 later.)

What is the “shuffle notation”?

I mean the notation $Sh(i_1, \ldots, i_k)$.
